# Read the maxJsonLength from web.config

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, web-config

I need to read the maxJsonLength from the web.config at runtime

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="3000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
```

Simply instantiating a new JavaScriptSerializer and reading the MaxJsonLength property shows the default of 2097152 regardless of the setting for the web service.

Why?

We have a asmx web service that returns Json and in extreme cases the data being returned cannot be converted into Json by the built in serializer and we get an ugly error. All other exceptions are captured and the service returns a sanitised custom exception.

If I can read the maxJsonLength value and manually attempt to serialize in code then I can capture the exception and handle it correctly.

I cannot have a duplicate of maxJsonLength in AppSettings just for this purpose.

Is there a generic way of arbitrary parsing the web.config to get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
string str = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.ToString();
Configuration conf = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(str);
ScriptingJsonSerializationSection section = (ScriptingJsonSerializationSection)conf.GetSection("system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/jsonSerialization");
int Length = section.MaxJsonLength; // Access length here
```

Comment: That works! I will have to cache the value to avoid repeatedly opening the web.config file for each request.

Comment: Please write this in application related event. whenever you change this value do not forgot to restart your application in IIS.

Comment: Updating the web.config would restart the app pool and thanks for your help.